# Comparing all columns in file to reference column in same file when it is not equal to zero

Tags: linux, awk

I have a TAB file with the following format:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  MSHR0491_Australasia    MSHR1539    MSHR1782    MSHR1887    MSHR1895
MSHR1153_annotated_1    9100    .   C   G   .   PASS    TYPE=snp    GT  0   1   0   0   0
MSHR1153_annotated_1    9107    .   C   A   .   PASS    TYPE=snp    GT  1   0   0   0   0
MSHR1153_annotated_1    9186    .   G   T   .   PASS    TYPE=snp    GT  0   0   1   1   1
MSHR1153_annotated_1    9197    .   C   T   .   PASS    TYPE=snp    GT  1   0   0   0   0
```

The goal is to print column 1 , 2 , 4 , 5 when the sample columns (MSHR**** columns) are not = 0. This is what I came up with using awk:

```
awk '$13 != 0 { print $1 $2 $4 $5}' FILE > MSHR***
```

The problem is this works when working with three samples however it is a bigger issue when working with 300 samples. Is there a way to get it to start at column 10  and then go through each column afterwards and create a file for each sample? Im pretty lost at the moment.

The expected output would be a file  called MSHR0491_Australasia with the columns printed:

```
MSHR1153_annotated_1_9107CA
MSHR1153_annotated_1_9197CT
```

A specific file for MSHR1539

```
MSHR1153_annotated_1_9100CG
```

Another file for  MSHR1782

```
MSHR1153_annotated_1_9186GT
```

etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the headers to use them for filenames and use a for loop, from the first sample to the last one.

```
awk 'NR==1{for (i=10;i<=NF;i++) col[i]=$i; next} 
          {for (i=10;i<=NF;i++) if ($i!=0) print $1 $2 $4 $5 > col[i] }' file
```

Output:

```
> for f in MSHR*; do printf "  => %s\n" "$f"; cat "$f"; done
  => MSHR0491_Australasia
MSHR1153_annotated_19107CA
MSHR1153_annotated_19197CT
  => MSHR1539
MSHR1153_annotated_19100CG
  => MSHR1782
MSHR1153_annotated_19186GT
  => MSHR1887
MSHR1153_annotated_19186GT
  => MSHR1895
MSHR1153_annotated_19186GT
```

---

In case you get any error about too many files open, here is a memory consuming  alternative:

```
awk 'NR==1{for (i=10;i<=NF;i++) col[i]=$i; next}
     {
         for (i=10;i<=NF;i++) {
             if ($i!=0) { 
                 x = $1 $2 $4 $5
                 f[col[i]] = f[col[i]]? f[col[i]] ORS x: x
             }
         }
     }
     END {for (i in f) {print f[i] > i; close(i)}}' file
```